# Hybris store creation

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, hybris-data-hub

Hi I have done with initial setup of hybris and now I am seeing apparel store. Now could you please someone answer how should I proceed further to completely customize the apparel store site. I wanted to remove all the products and I wanted to add my own products and categories . Also where should I change the URL from apparelstore to my own customized URL?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own accelerator module. There is a trail called "commerce trail" on the hybris wiki/help pages that helps you with the initial setup of a module.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to follow the help section about how to customize the accelerator (e.g: [b2c accelerator customization](https://help.hybris.com/6.7.0/hcd/8ace75c786691014a5e9dcafa29d5410.html)). Generally speaking, you can use the `ant modulegen` command to generate the extensions for your very own accelerator.

For your own products/categories, you should provide them on impex files. The current data you're seeing is from the apparelstore extension that adds products, categories, site configuration & cms content for the apparel store. So in case you don't want that, you need to remove the apparelstore extension (or don't run projectdata for it) and then provide your own data. You can check that extension also and see how the data is created, to use it as a guide, but also the `ant modulegen` should generate some impex file templates that you can use. Look in `hybris/bin/ext-data/apparelstore/resources/apparelstore/import`.

Finally, for your urls, please check the CMSSite url parameters, this are the urls that 'activate' the site for the given request. Also search for properties like `website.{siteid}.http=` & `website.{siteid}.https=` that you also need to update for everything to work fine.